# Merge ttf files

Tags: fonts, merge

Does anyone know how what is the best way to merge different ttf files. I mean font files.
I have two ttf file and I want to have one where English characters are taken from the first one and Japanese from another one.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/q/490922

Answer (score 17):

Copy and paste using a font editor. I have used [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/) (open source, free, Windows, OSX, Linux) and [FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com/) (commercial, Windows, OSX) in the past with good results.

Comment: This will work for getting the glyph outlines merged together, but will most likely alter other information in the fonts. For TrueType, that means the instructions (hints), which can sometimes cause the fonts' appearance to change, especially at smaller sizes. There may be other side-effects as well. I say this not to discourage you but just understand that it's not always so simple.

Comment: @djangodude I think FontForge has ways to fix the hints or automatically make them better. Anyhow, for the current scenario, mixing Japanese with all others will have no ill effects when using the font (I don't know of any words mixing such characters).

Comment: Right, FontForge has a way to automatically apply hints to a font, but that does not necessarily improve the font. Particularly in the case of a font that has had considerable attention to the hints ("manual hinting"); FontForge's autohints generally won't be better than manual hints...and can be quite a bit worse.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to merge fonts then [TransType](http://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/) from FontLab is a good option. I'm not affiliated, just been using that app for over a decade!